# finding the average and std across multiple Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series, standard-deviation

I have a list of (let's say 100) objects, each containing a pandas series. All series data has the same length (let's say 400). I would like to calculate the average and the series data so that I get a two series, the same size as the other series (400).

Is there a short way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need join them together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and use [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
s1 = pd.Series(range(3))
s2 = pd.Series([4,5,7])
s3 = pd.Series([7,5,2])

L = [s1, s2, s3]

df = pd.concat(L, axis=1).agg(['mean','std'], axis=1)
print (df)
       mean       std
0  3.666667  3.511885
1  3.666667  2.309401
2  3.666667  2.886751
```

---

```
print (df['mean'])
0    3.666667
1    3.666667
2    3.666667
Name: mean, dtype: float64

print (df['std'])
0    3.511885
1    2.309401
2    2.886751
Name: std, dtype: float64
```